# How do I restore my position in a CoordinatorLayout after rotation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

When I scroll to the bottom of my NestedScrollView and rotate the device my position in the list is saved but when I rotate back to portrait mode the ImageView in the AppBarLayout is expanded instead of collapsed like it was when I originally rotated the screen. I want to return to how it was prior to rotation, with the image either partially collapsed or completely collapsed.

---

**Prior to device rotation**

[image: [1]]

---

**After device rotation**

[image: [2]]

XML File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/album_art"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                android:src="@drawable/the_getaway_album"
                android:contentDescription="@string/album_art_description" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/standard_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/album_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/explicitness"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/standard_padding"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_filled"
                    android:text="@string/explicit_tag"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/standard_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/artist"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/release_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/album_price"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/large_price_bubble_length"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/standard_text_size"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/copyright"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/track_list_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/standard_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/track_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add configChanges param to manifest file it worked for me,

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: In marshmallow its working fine, which device your testing

Comment: this answer is completely unrelated to the question at hand. This piece of code disables screen rotation altogether, which is not the desired behavior